# libsvm class not found in weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, libsvm

I installed LibSVM in weka from package manager and it is successfully installed. But when I am running the following command-

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier  -F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType  -W weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM  -t training.arff -no-cv -T testing.arff  -v -o
```

it Shows that

```
Can't find class called: weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM
```

But other classifiers like `Naive Bayes` is working. Why it's not finding the class. I am using mac.

Answer (score 4):

Weka.jar does not contain LibSVM class. So, to use LibSVM, you have to provide LibSVM.jar in classpath along with weka.jar. You can download LibSVM.jar from

1. www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm+tar.gz (tar.gz)
2. www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm+zip (Zip file)

   You can provide LibSVM.jar in classpath as follows:

java -classpath $pathtoweka.jar/weka.jar:$pathtoLibSVM.jar/libsvm.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t $pathtotrainfile -x 10 -c last -i -d $pathtomodel -F 'weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R 1 -W 3000 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -T -I -M 1 -tokenizer weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -C'  -W weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM -- -B

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can understand the last part. I have training and testing set as a vector in arff file. Can not i use those? What is model here($parhtomodel)?

Comment: Do i need to change the aarf file into libsvm supported file?

Comment: As far as I Know libSvm don't require any special arff structure, So you may not need to change arff structure. However, I don't know wheather it accepts float(if vectors are float) values as features. $pathtomodel refers to model generated after training.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, the objects in the links are nor found.

Comment: @F505 They might be removed from the location.....Just search LibSVM jar download on google and you will get the jars